# Numpy broadcast 3-d matrix and 1d vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `A` of the shape `(N, N, T)`. Then I have a vector of `V` shape `(N,)`. I want to perform the following operation `A[i, j, ...]` = `A[i, j, ...]*V[i]/V[j]`. I'm doing this with the following loop, but sure there is a way to do it with broadcast.

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 2, 3))
V = np.array([2, 3]) 

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        A[i, j, ...] *= V[i]
        A[i, j, ...] /= V[j]
```

I've thought about doing it with element-wise multiplication and broadcast of numpy, and I try approaches like A * `V[:, None, None]` but always got an error.

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it -

```
(A*V[:,None,None])/V[:,None]
```

Alternatively, in two steps -

```
A *= V[:,None,None]
A /= V[:,None]
```

Leverage `multi-cores` with `numexpr` -

```
import numexpr as ne
ne.evaluate('A*V3D/V2D',{'V3D':V[:,None,None],'V2D':V[:,None]})
```

Note that you might be getting error because you might be doing edits into an int array with float results. So, either convert to float array at the start or write to a new array with the one-step approaches.